# selection sort using recursion

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, selection-sort, function-definition

```
void swap(int a[], int x, int y)
{

    int temp = a[x];
    a[x] = a[y];
    a[y] = temp;
}
void sort(int arr[], int x)
{
    static int count = 0;
    if (x == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    int min = 100;    //  random value
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    swap(arr, count, index);
    count++;
    sort(arr + 1, x - 1);
}
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    int A[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    sort(A, x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this code is of selection sort using recursion. It is printing garbage values. what's the mistake in this. i am not sure but i guess because of using the static variable in the sort function(). it is printing garbage values

Comment: FYI, [variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/11082165) like `int A[x];` are not legal in standard C++. Using a construct like that is only possible with non-standard compiler extensions to the C++ language. Also, re: initializing `min` to `-1` with the comment _"random value because given arrays have positive elements"_, when will `(positive element) < min` be true?

Comment: With the static variable it's unable to call the function twice. Why not declaring `sort(int arr[], int first, int last)`?

Comment: Just remove count and any its usage. You already did arr + 1 and count makes swap min with arr + 1 + count that leads half of attempts to access outside the array.

Comment: "random value" comment reminded me something from badcode website or something similar .. `const int  rnd = 13; // a random value obtained by throwing a d20 dice`

Comment: Don’t use recursion where no recursion is needed (e.g. in this case). That would have avoided most of the problems. Also, never use `static` local variables unless you (a) know very precisely what you are doing or (b) hate recursion and hate multi-threading, both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `swap(arr, count, index);` with

```
swap(arr, 0, index);
```

and remove `static int count = 0;`.

Replace `sort(A, x);` in the main with

```
sort(A, x - 1);
```

and change the condition `if (x == 1)` to `if (x == 0)`.

I suggest to rename `index` to `last`.

Replace `min = 100;` with

```
min = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters variable length arrays like this

```
int x;
cin >> x;
int A[x];
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

Nevertheless the function can invoke undefined behavior when for example is called with the second parameter equal to `0`.

Also there is no sense to declare the static variable.

The function will not sort an array elements of which have values greater than 100.

The variable `index` must be initialized to 0 before the for loop.

Also there is already the standard function `std::swap` that swaps two objects.

The function can be defined the following way

```
#include <algorithm>

void selection_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( not ( n < 2 ) )
    {
        auto it = std::min_element( a, a + n );

        if ( it != a ) std::iter_swap( a, it );

        selection_sort( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

If you do not know yet standard algorithms then the functions can look the following way

```
void swap( int &a, int &b )
{
    int rmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

void selection_sort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( not ( n < 2 ) )
    {
        size_t index = 0;

        for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( a[i] < a[index] ) index = i;
        }

        if ( index != 0 ) swap( a[0], a[index] );  

        selection_sort( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways of doing the selection sort using recursion is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void selectionSort(int *arr, int size,int minIndex){
    //base case
    if(size ==0 || size ==1 || minIndex == size){
        return;
    }

    //processing
    for(int i=minIndex+1;i<size;i++){
        if(arr[i]<arr[minIndex]){
            swap(arr[minIndex], arr[i]);
        }
    }
    //recursive call
    selectionSort(arr,size,minIndex+1);
}


int main(){

   int arr[7]={7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    int size = 7;
    int minIndex = 0;
    selectionSort(arr,size,minIndex);
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

We are creating a minIndex at the starting of the array and comparing it with the values in the remaining array, to get the minimum value of the whole array on the left-most side. At each recursive call, we will increment the place of minIndex for further comparison. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
a=[6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1]

length=a.length

cur=0

n=cur+1

function fun(n)

{

    if(cur==length-1)
    {
        return a
    }
    else if(a[cur]>a[n])
    {
        temp=a[cur]
        a[cur]=a[n]
        a[n]=temp
        if(n==length-1)
        {
            n=cur
            cur++
        }
        // console.log(a)
        // console.log(cur)
        return fun(n+1)
    }
    else
    {
         if(n==length-1)
        {
            n=cur
            cur++
        }
         return fun(n+1)
    }
   
}

let t=[]

t=[...fun(n)]

console.log(t)
```

Comment: Please try to add some supporting information to your post that explains what your code does. There appears to be issues with formatting in your answer as well, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help